# Changing color of a single cell in WPF Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5

I have a WPF Datagrid with variable number of columns and populated at runtime with a 2D array of String[][].

```
String[] data = .....;

datagrid.ItemsSource = data;
```

I need to chance cell colors based on its values. But these values are defined by the user during execution. Most examples I found about changing cell colors use Triggers on the XAML and the value is known in design time.

So I'm changing the background of the cell like this:

```
DataGridCell cell = DataGridUtils.GetCell(datagrid, i, j);

cell.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkGreen);
```

And the GetCell function:

```
private DataGridCell GetCell(int rowIndex, int colIndex, DataGrid dg)
{
    DataGridRow row = dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(rowIndex) as DataGridRow;
    DataGridCellsPresenter p = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(row);
    DataGridCell cell = p.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(colIndex) as DataGridCell;

    return cell;
}
```

At first glance it seems to be doing ok, I can see the cell with that value in green. But if I scroll the datagrid all the way down and then go back up the cell in green changes do another random cell nad more cells are turning green. If I keep going up and down the cells in green keep changing randomly.

I know this sounds very weird, but there's only one place in code that changes cell colors, and it's in a button click. I don't know how this could be happening when scrolling the datagrid.

I read somewhere that ItemContainerGenerator it's not an elegant solution and should be avoided. But it's the only way I managed to make this work.

Is there better way to change background color of a cell? Can I do this with Triggers without knowing the values at design time? If so, how?

Comment: What is the logic for determining the color?

Comment: The user types a value and then these values are colored on the datagrid

Comment: You don't need to abandon the nice feature Virtualizing by setting `VirtualizingMode` to `Standard`. You can handle the event `LoadingRow` to update the background there and also handle the `UnloadingRow` to restore the background to some default value. I've just tested it on a `DataGridRow` (not a `DataGridCell`) but it proves that way is very prospective. Virtualizing has its own way to deal with this problem.

Comment: @KingKing You'll encounter problems when you scroll the grid fast and notice the background is lagging.

Comment: @lll it's acceptable at some sense. However the advantage is saving memory (because the virtualizing is still used), the disadvantage of turning virtualizing is consuming large memory. So following this or that depending on some criteria. Trying scrolling the grid fast is something abnormal. If you always try doing something ***fast*** like that, you would feel that WPF in fact does not perform well (like as advertised).

Comment: A simple example of doing ***fast*** makes us unsatisfied: Try resizing the window as fast as possible, how flickering it is? At least that happens in Windows 7 and on almost windows.

Comment: @KingKing I agree. However, what if the `DataCell` depend on serialization and you need the `DataCell`' color to be apply the correct background. `Loading/Unloaded` events will not help you here. It's always a trade off and depending on his use case if what's the gain and loss.

Comment: @lll not sure what you meant here, in `LoadingRow` and `UnloadingRow` handlers, we always have access to the related row via the argument's `Row` property. The only disadvantage I realized about this approach is the performance (I've already run a simple demo with it, the performance to highlight a row is OK, but for some specific cells is not really good - the UI is fairly OK but the CPU usage is fairly high when scrolling).

Comment: @KingKing I'm talking about `Serialization` using `XamlWriter/XamlReader`.

Comment: @lll do you mean when using Serialization, we cannot add any event handlers for the DataGrid? serialization to send/save it, deserialization to get it back, once getting it back, you use it normally as an instance of DataGrid.

Comment: @KingKing You can add event handlers but I'm saying if you needed the `Background` to apply the correct color right away. It won't work. When you `deserialize` it add it to the `VisualTree` expect that the `Background` will be wrong and the `Loaded` will not be fired even if you see it in the being added to the DataGrid.

Comment: @lll I don't really understand that scenario, looks like you mean adding the row dynamically at runtime? I'm not sure if it could work in such a case. The `LoadingRow` should be fired whenever a row becomes visible (that's all I know about virtualizing mode of DataGrid). Also note that the events I talked about here are `LoadingRow` and `UnloadingRow` (not the `Loaded` event).

Comment: @KingKing Yes adding it at runtime. It does work and there are use cases for that. And no, loading will not be fired because sometimes the `Dispatcher` can have timing issues.

Comment: @lll I hope what you said comes from your experience, you may want to try some simple demo to experience it. For my part, I've not experienced much about even the DataGrid control, that will happen when some project need it.

Comment: @KingKing Lol, I don't need a demo because it's based on my experience.

Comment: @lll and I hope the `Loaded` event (in your previous comments) was meant by you as `LoadingRow` (`Loaded` has nothing to do here in this discussion). (I was fairly experienced in some fields, but after a long time without working in those fields, I was almost new again - I mean my experience in those fields went away).

Comment: @KingKing Yes, `LoadingRow`. Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataGrid` has `VirtualizationMode` default to `Recycling` which means it'll reuse the `DataCell` that it generated to improve performance. It won't have to create **n times** of controls.

Add this to your `DataGrid`

```
VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"
```

Be aware that it'll affect your performance and WPF will create **n times** of control.